# rtMavenRun() Artifactory plugin not using credentials configured in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

This is my pipeline:

```
stage('Deploy') {
    environment {
        MAVEN_HOME = '/usr/share/maven'
        JAVA_HOME= '/usr/local/openjdk-8'
    }
    steps {
        rtMavenResolver (
                id: 'resolver-unique-id',
                serverId: 'my-server-config',
                releaseRepo: 'my-repo',
                snapshotRepo: 'my-repo'
        )
        rtMavenDeployer (
                id: 'deployer-unique-id',
                serverId: 'my-server-config',
                releaseRepo: 'my-repo',
                snapshotRepo: 'my-repo'
        )
        rtMavenRun (
                pom: 'pom.xml',
                goals: 'help:effective-settings',
                //goals: 'deploy',
                resolverId: 'resolver-unique-id',
                deployerId: 'deployer-unique-id'
        )

        // This works
        rtPublishBuildInfo (
            serverId: 'my-server-config'
        )
```

I have the creds and URL configured on jenkins (my-server-config). I know it's configured correctly because rtPublishBuildInfo() works and publishes to Artifactory. The user it's using is a full admin so should be no perms issues.

This is running in a container slave so I had to manually set environment to point to the locations of Maven and Java home for the plugin to find it. It's running the official Maven image

When I try the deploy goal (confirmed working locally with same user creds) I see this error:

```
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - Could not transfer metadata com.mycompany.app:my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshots (https://my-tenant.jfrog.io/my-tenant/my-repo): Not authorized
```

I tried running the `help:effective-settings` goal and checked jenkins output. It looks like it's not using my creds? How does this plugin even work with the Jenkins cred binding I set in the config? How does it pass those creds to mvn?

```
Effective user-specific configuration settings:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2019-10-18T19:04:34Z                 -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective Settings for 'root' on 'mypackagepackage-2zbtg-hsxqv'   -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>/root/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.apache.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

### Edit 1

Now I think the plugin is totally broken I tried explicitly passing it a global settings file with the right creds and it's *still* failing:

```
rtMavenRun (
        pom: 'pom.xml',
        //global-settings here is a jenkins secret file with the entire contents of a global settings.xml
        goals: '--settings ${global-settings} deploy',
        resolverId: 'resolver-unique-id',
        deployerId: 'deployer-unique-id'
)
```

I'm seeing this error:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project my-app: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

### Edit 2

OK so even though this works fine locally I tried setting an updated version of the deployment plugin in my pom:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
  </plugin>
```

And now I'm getting *another* error from the plugin (this still works locally without issue):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 409 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
The target deployment path 'com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-20191018.195756-35/my-app-1.0-20191018.195756-35.pom' does not match the POM's expected path prefix 'com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT'. Please verify your POM content for correctness and make sure the source path is a valid Maven repository root path. Status code: 40
```

### Edit 3

Continuing my epic struggle with this crap-ass jfrog plugin I disabled consistency checks on the local repo and it can deploy but now I understand that error. It's transforming my pom and turning `1.0-SNAPSHOT` into `1.0-20191018.195756-35` why is it doing that and how to a get it to not mangle my pom file?

### Edit 4

I must be a moron or documentation is not very clear (maybe both). I was using the deploy goal because I wanted to deploy. But apparently you don't do that with the plugin- this makes sense to me now. You `clean` and `install` the package but leave it to the plugin to deploy it so it puts it in the right location and attaches build info. Using `install` as a goal works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is don't use `deploy` goal. Build the package and the plugin will take care of the deployment part.

Comment: Right. To be more precised,  make sure to use the install goal,  which the Artifactory deployment is hooked into.

Comment: I also need to run the 'test' phase. Will the artifactory plugin do anything weird with that? I'd like to use it for test phase too because injects credentials

Comment: You can simply add test to the list of maven goals - "clean install test package". Let me know if it works for you. You also have the option of deploying to Artifactory at a later stage, after the build finished. See the documentation for how to do this.

Comment: its needs to be done in a separate step. so just `clean` `test` will be run in one stage then `clean` `install` will be run in the next. I dont want to deploy and test in the same stage

Comment: You can do "clean install test" with deployArtifacts set to false, and deploy at a later stage using rtMaven.deployer.deloy()